# How to override HTMLTags LabelFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Using [HTMLTags](https://github.com/HtmlTags/htmltags) and [JimmyMVC conventions](http://steventcramer.github.io/blog/2015/08/23/jimmy-mvc/) I have in a view the following:

```
@Html.FormBlock(aModel => aModel.PostQuery.ProjectId)
```

But the label is generated as "PostQueryProjectId"

How can I override the generator to just return "ProjectId"?

Answer (score 1):

Add annotation in PostQuery model

```
class PostQuery
{
[Display(Name="Post Query")]
public int ProjectId {get; set; }
...
}
```

Comment: Alexander, Yes this will work but would require for every attribute.  I am looking to override the LabelFor generator to only show the last property name not the whole chain to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Steven,

I think you can override the conventions by implementing your own HtmlConventionRegistry

```
public class DefaultAspNetMvcHtmlConventions : HtmlConventionRegistry
{
    public DefaultAspNetMvcHtmlConventions()
    {
        Labels.Always.ModifyWith(er => er.CurrentTag.Text(er.Accessor.Name));
    }
}
```

Then apply your registry before adding it to your IoC container (here is mine for structuremap)

```
public class HtmlTagRegistry : Registry
{
    public HtmlTagRegistry()
    {
        var htmlConventionLibrary = new HtmlConventionLibrary();
        new DefaultHtmlConventions().Apply(htmlConventionLibrary);
        new DefaultAspNetMvcHtmlConventions().Apply(htmlConventionLibrary);
        For<HtmlConventionLibrary>().Use(htmlConventionLibrary);
    }
}
```